# Fixing memory leak of EF4.1 context + Ninject combo

Tags: entity-framework, memory-leaks, ninject, named-scope, ninject-conventions

I have a windows service which periodically runs some jobs using NCron. I recently introduced Ninject and got some serious memory issues due to the fact that the EF context (ObjectContext from EF4.1) is not GC'ed (I memory-profiled it).

It might be worth mentioning that some of these jobs are quite long running (10-15min) and are database intensive. I know EF is probably not the best solution for this kind of work but this it's impossible to refactor at this point.

I found quite a bit of material on this subject so I went ahead with:

1. Implementing INotifyWhenDisposed in my job classes
2. Trying to define EF context binding in a named scope, hoping it'll get disposed and GC'ed properly when the job is finished

I cannot seem to get the 2nd one to work, I get an ActivationException that the named scope does not exist.

Here's a simple piece of code I tried in debug mode that replicates this:

```
const string Scope = "Scope";
kernel.Bind(c => c.FromThisAssembly()
        .SelectAllClasses().InheritedFrom<MyCronJob>()
        .BindToSelf()
        .Configure(b => b.DefinesNamedScope(Scope)));

kernel.Bind<IMyContext>().To<MyContext>().InNamedScope(Scope);
kernel.Get<ProcessImportJob>().DoWork();
```

And then

```
internal class ProcessImportJob : MyCronJob
{
    private readonly IMyContext _ctx;

    public ProcessImportJob(IMyContext ctx)
```

I cut the rest for brevity.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE 1** - Constructor injection works, it's when I do an explicit `.Get<T>` that the exception occurs.

Comment: Can you show the code that begins and ends the scope? Somewhere your contexts stay referenced. Do your jobs get cached somewhere?

Comment: Hi, there isn't really any other relevant piece of code. Nevermind the service, you can run this as a console app, the first piece of code is found in `static Main` and the 2nd is my job class (which is IDisposable also if that helps). The issue is not the memory leak here but the fact that I get an ActivationException that it cannot find the named scope.